# How to separate binary strings from text file and store them in 1d or 2d char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

"01110011 01100001 01100100 " This would be one line having the 8 bits separated by spaces in the file.

Currently I have:

```
if (fr != NULL) //see if file opens or not
{
    char chter[500]; //char to get string from text
    char *ptr; //pointer to char

    //char store[100][32];

    fgets(chter, 1000, fr); //gets text from file   

    printf("%s", chter); //prints current text to cmd from textfile
    puts("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {           
        li1 = strtol(chter, &ptr, 2); //convert 1st binary set to alphabet
        printf("%c", li1); //Not sure how to get the rest of the sets from here on
    }
    puts("\n");

    fclose(fr);
}
```

I was thinking of using a 2d array to have multiple strings stored, however I'm stuck. As I don't know how to seperatly extract the binary bits from the other string.

Comment: What language are you using? Looks like `C` or `C++` to me..., please tag the language.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that. It's C.

Answer (score 0):

After each call to `strtol`, `ptr` will point to the first byte in the string that's not part of the parsed integer.  That will be your starting point on the next iteration.  Since `fgets` returns a string with a newline, loop until `ptr` points to either the newline or the null byte at the end of the string.

```
char *ptr, *tmp;

tmp = chter;
do
{
    li1 = strtol(tmp, &ptr, 2);
    printf("%c", li1);
    tmp = ptr;
} while ((*ptr != '\n') && (*ptr != '\0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem you have is failing to use separate pointers for `strtol (ptr, &endptr, 2)` which would then allow you to work through all values held in `chter`. Secondly, you risk Undefined Behavior by potentially reading `1000` characters where `chter` will only hold `500`. Thirdly, you need to properly ***validate*** the results of the `strtol` conversion by checking (1) whether digits were converted; and (2) whether *overflow/undeflow* occurred by checking `errno`.

Putting those together, you could do:

```
#include <errno.h>
...
if (fr != NULL) //see if file opens or not
{
    char chter[500];    //char to get string from text
    char *ptr = chter;  /* assign chter to the pointer */
    char *endptr;       /* separate end-pointer for strtol */

    fgets(chter, sizeof chter, fr); /* properly limit read size */

    printf("%s", chter); //prints current text to cmd from textfile
    puts("\n");

    errno = 0;                      /* set errno zero */
    while (*ptr && *ptr != '\n')    /* loop over all values */
    {           
        long li1 = strtol (ptr, &endptr, 2);    /* convert to long */
        if (ptr == endptr) {        /* validate digits converted */
            fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
            /* handle error */
            break;
        }
        else if (errno) {           /* validate no over/underflow */
            perror ("strtol-conversion_failed");
            /* handle error */
            break;
        }
        printf (" %ld", li1);       /* output value */
        ptr = endptr;               /* advance pointer */
    }
    // puts("\n");
    putchar ('\n');     /* use putchar for single-char output */

    fclose(fr);
}
```

(**note:** not compiled, so drop a note if you have problems)